# Google Maps API v3: Custom overlay with canvas drawing not receiving events in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, browser, dom-events

I am trying to implement a custom overlay in Google Maps API v3, with some custom drawing done through a canvas element. Basically I am reproducing the Polygon element from the API, but with the ability to receive events from the user (the goal is to drop some stuff on the zone, with native drag'n drop).

So drawing works fine, I attach a listener to the canvas element and that's where trouble happens. Safari (tested with 5.1.4) delivers the event, until I do some drawing on the canvas element by retrieving the context and adding a path. For Chrome (17), Firefox (10), and Opera (11), no issues.

You can view the page [here](http://dev.vicould.net/simple_event.html). When you click on the gray polygon on the center of the map, a `plop` should be added below the map, as a check that the event was delivered.

Here are some parts of the code, first creating the overlay and adding it to the panes.

```
EventReceiverOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {
  var holder = document.createElement('canvas');
  holder.style.opacity = 0.5;
  this.canvas_ = holder;

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(holder, 'click', function(event) {
/*      holder.addEventListener('click', function(event) { */
    document.getElementById('message_container').innerHTML += 'plop';
  }, false);

  this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(holder);
}
```

Then drawing the overlay (updateScreenPoints allows to convert all the coordinates of the points to pixel coordinates):

```
EventReceiverOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {
  var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

  var swCorner = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
  var neCorner = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

  this.updateScreenPoints();
  var canvas = this.canvas_;

  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.save();

    ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.style.width, canvas.style.height);

    canvas.style.position = 'relative';
    canvas.style.left = Math.round(swCorner.x) + 'px';
    canvas.style.top = Math.round(neCorner.y) + 'px';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.screenPoints_[0].x, this.screenPoints_[0].y);
    for (var i = 1; i < this.screenPoints_.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(this.screenPoints_[i].x, this.screenPoints_[i].y);
    }
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
  }

}
```

I tested with different events (click, mouseover, dragenter, etc.), different ways to attach the event (through `google.maps.event.addDOMListener`, browser `addEventListener`, and jQuery `on`), with the same results: Safari refuses to play nicely, whereas the others work as expected, triggering my function.

I also tried to add the overlay to another map pane, such as the overlayMouseTarget or the floatPane, with no additional changes.

To give another try, I implemented a simple canvas (with the same shape, more or less the same drawing process) to test if Safari receives the event in that case, and yes, it's working.

Doing the same with a simple div element works perfectly, the issue happens as soon as I begin to draw on the canvas.

I am not sure of what I did wrong, or if there is a bug between the Google Maps API and Safari. So your help will be greatly appreciated, if you manage to go through the whole story I just wrote :)

Thanks

**Edit**
Apparently as Brendan Kenny reports there are no issues with OS X 10.6.8 and Safari 5.1.2. I tested it with OS X 10.6.8 and Safari 5.0.5, and no issues as well.

I made a second page, [here](http://dev.vicould.net/no_drawing.html), with no other changes than removing the drawing part (I deleted all the parts that were using the context from the canvas in the `draw` method). When clicking on the red rectangle, a "plop" is added to the div below, and it works as expected in Safari 5.1.4.

**Edit 2**
Fixed in Safari 6.0, guess I won't know what happened.

Comment: To be clear: the expected behavior is that clicks on the canvas that contains the grey polygon should add a 'plop' to the div below the map? What OS are you running? On OS X 10.6.8 (running Safari 5.1.2), the plop appears whenever I click on the canvas on the page, and appears to have all the same reactions as Chrome.

Comment: Yep exactly, it should add a plop in the div below the map when clicking on the grey polygon.
I am running OS X 10.7.3, with Safari 5.1.4. I will try to test on older versions of Safari, if I can find one, and update the question with the results.

Answer (score 1):

Google *really* doesn't like this technique. Their canvas and your canvas will fight for z-index, only one will receive the mouse event, and either A) your stuff will work, but you won't be able to click/pan/zoom the map or B) vice versa. You might be able to get it to work sometimes, but then after panning the map it won't work because the new tiles will come in at a higher z-index. If you add Google's controls or try to use two-finger trackpad zooming, you'll see those don't work.

Use Google's Polygon class etc and all should be right with the world. I speak from experience -- I tried to do my project this way and hit the same wall. I bent to Google's will and everything is groovy.

Comment: I am not completely sure of what you mean by "Google really doesn't like this technique". To implement the overlay, which in my case is a kind of a polygon, I am following the example give in the Google Maps Javascript API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#CustomOverlays).

The EventReceiverOverlay is created with the google.maps.OverlayView prototype, so there shouldn't be my canvas vs. their canvas, just our shared which is refreshed calling the here overridden draw method.

Comment: At first I thought you were appending an additional <canvas> element to the OverlayView. So now I agree that this *should* work.

But, you'll notice that Google's draw example does *not* manipulate the internal "canvas_" property. I'm guessing the trailing underscore is meant to indicate that it's a private member?

Instead, use your points to create a Google-approved Polygon and add that to your map. (examples on the same page)

Comment: The issue with the Google-approved Polygon is that you cannot have access to the associated HTML element, and therefore it is not possible to add any listener to it (unless I missed something). Again, what I did is working perfectly in Chrome, Opera, Firefox, and Safari versions older than 5.1.4, so for me the issue is specific to Safari.

Comment: When you create the Polygon, you can add "clickable: true" to the options object passed to the constructor. Afterwards, google.maps.event.addListener(shapeView, "click", clickHandler);

Comment: Well I don't need to listen to the click event, I am implementing a drag'n drop interface with the drop zones being the overlays. The Maps API seems to only provide the "click", "dblclick", "mouseup", "mousedown", "mouseover", and "mouseout" events. I'll test specifying another type of event and come back with the results.

Comment: As I thought, the dragenter/dragover/dragleave/drop events are not triggered if added through addEventListener on the polygon, although doing that with addDomEventListener on an html tag works.

Comment: Can you try setting a flag when dragging starts and then check the polygon for mouseup + flag to detect "drop"?

Comment: Well, it's starting to go totally outside of the scope of what I am doing in my project. So yeah it could be a possibility, but it will cut a lot of features I am implementing. And again, it _works_ with Opera, Firefox, Chrome, and pre-5.1.3 Safari versions (I need to find a Windows PC somewhere to test on IE).

Comment: I looked at your code again, and noticed that you *are* adding your own canvas which *will* conflict with the one used for the underlying map. Google's code will mess with the z-indexing which I'm guessing is the root cause of the whole problem. I've been wrong before, so if you get this technique working, I'd *love* to see it. ;) You might want to try console.log-ing the z-index on a timer and see if you can find some kind of pattern to the swap. *Maybe* it'd be possible to un-do Google's change...

Comment: I checked and there are no other canvas elements on the map except the one I build. Google Maps uses simple div with css transforms to display the tiles of the map. I don't have any z-index for my canvas, and setting one (even super-high) does not change anything to the event reception.